# What could be the best way to get file path

Tags: c#

I have 3 different directories where files are available for further processing.

1. May be some directory not exist, hence I put `try/catch`.
2. As soon as a single file available in any directory, I am returning the path.

Here is below code, question, what could be the best way to get file path as above functionality?

```
private static string GetRealPath()
    {
        const string filePath1 = @"C:\temp1\";
        const string filePath2 = @"C:\temp2\";
        const string filePath3 = @"C:\temp\";

        //looks for file in  @"C:\temp1\ 
        try
        {
            if (Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(filePath1, "*.txt").ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                return filePath1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }

        //looks for file in  @"C:\temp2\ 
        try
        {
            if (Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(filePath2, "*.txt").ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                return filePath2;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }

        //looks for file in  @"C:\temp\ 
        try
        {
            if (Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(filePath3, "*.txt").ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                return filePath3;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: "May be some directory not exist, hence I put try/catch" - it sounds to me like you should be using `Directory.Exists`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get the path of? temp?

Comment: Get path to what?

Comment: `EnumerateFileSystemEntries(filePath3, "*.txt").ToList().Count > 0` is extremely inefficient, especially on a directory with many files. You are always going through each file to figure out if there is one or more. You should use `EnumerateFileSystemEntries(filePath3, "*.txt").Any()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Directory.Exists` instead:

```
public static string GetFirstValidPath()
{
    string[] paths = { @"C:\temp1\", @"C:\temp2\", @"C:\temp\"};
    return paths.FirstOrDefault(p=> Directory.Exists(p) 
       && Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(p, "*.txt").Any()) ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Minor issue: your answer will return `default(string)` on no match, instead of `string.Empty`, and `default(string) != string.Empty`.

Comment: @user584018: return `String.Empty` instead. Fixed. Instead you could have handled it also where you call this method. Returning `null` seems to be the better option if there is no valid path.